# How can a type of a class field that is unknown at instantiation be inferred?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Here's a class example:

```js
class Foo {
  item: unknown

  constructor(item: unknown) {
    this.item = item 
  }

  getItem(): typeof this.item {
    return this.item
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkGzPW)

It throws an error: `Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name 'this'`

How otherwise can I type return value of `getItem` if it's unknown?

Comment: `Foo["item"]`? But note that's still `unknown`; maybe you should make it generic?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the answer! is there any better way to do it then? Essentially `item` can be anything, but i still wanna get strong typing when I'm calling `getItem`

Comment: It's not at all clear what the context is - again, maybe you want a generic type, but if the value isn't known until runtime then TypeScript can't help you with it anyway (because the types are erased by then).

Comment: @jonrsharpe, okay I understand what you mean now. Forgot that it's impossible to dynamically check types in typescript. Thanks!

Comment: (When I say generic, I'm imagining something like: https://tsplay.dev/w2aKVW)

Comment: @jonrsharpe, fantastic! Exactly what I needed. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it as a correct one.